# App that allows iPhones to share information while overseas without a plan (and no data)

Tags: iphone, applications, wifi, data

I need an app that allows a number of iPhones to exchange information between each other during an event that there may be no WiFi available while myself and two buddies travel overseas.

None of us plan on 'roaming' while overseas on our current plan, we strictly plan to either stick together, or communicate through wifi. But what happens if we get separated in a city and need to communicate when wifi is not available, like a walkie talkie function

Traveling in Europe.

Thanks for all the suggestions!
-Pad

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like [FireChat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firechat/id719829352?mt=8). I have not tried it personally, but it is touted as "a new way to chat: 'off-the-grid'." It uses iOS 7's mesh networking capabilities to achieve this.

> Now you can chat with people around you – even if there is no Internet
>   connection or mobile phone coverage.
>
> Whether you’re on the beach or in the subway, at a big game or a trade
>   show, camping in the wild or at a concert, or even travelling abroad,
>   simply fire up the app with a friend or two and find out who else is
>   there.

[...]

- Instantly chat with anyone around you on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch
- Works even without any Internet connection or mobile phone coverage
- Use the "Nearby" mode for off-the-grid communications, up to 200 feet of your location
- Multi-hop capabilities extend the range of peer-to-peer communications